# How do I make a message in the alert the same as in the alertcondition function?

Tags: pine-script

How do I make a message in the alert the same as in the alertcondition function?

```
//Condições Alertas
cond = long[1] ? 1 : short[1] ? -1 : 0

cond2 = fib0382[2] ? 2 : fib0618[2] ? -2 : 0

s01 = input.symbol('BINANCE:BTCUSDT')

a01 = request.security(s01, timeframe.period, cond)

cond01 = a01 == 1 ? 1 : a01 == -1 ? -1 : na

cond201 = a01 == 2 ? 2 : a01 == -2 ? -2 : na


if cond == 1
    alert("  CALL ! ! !       " + syminfo.ticker + "                     LONG " + "10x - 5x" + "                                           Price: (" + str.tostring(close) + ")" + "                                                                             Take: (" + str.tostring(fib0618) + ")" + "                                                                                             Stop: (" + str.tostring(fib0382) + ")", alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
else if cond == -1
    alert("  CALL ! ! !       " + syminfo.ticker + "                     SHORT " + "10x - 5x" + "                                           Price: (" + str.tostring(close) + ")" + "                                                                             Take: (" + str.tostring(fib0618) + ")" + "                                                                                             Stop: (" + str.tostring(fib0382) + ")", alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
```

Comment: What language is this? It certainly isn't php.

Comment: Please format your code better and tell us what programming language and libraries you use

Comment: it's pine script

Comment: Then why did you tag php? Please [edit] your post to be clearer.  See also [ask] for more general guidance on asking a successful question here